# How to style <select> with <mat-select> style?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm in a situation where I need to use both  and  tags in this project because in some situations the code breaks if I choose mat-select. But visually the select tag looks plain old ugly.

[image: This is what it looks like in select.]

[image: This is how it looks in mat-select and how I want it to look like.]

I tried looking for the CSS in Material Component documentation but wasn't able to find it. Do you guys have any suggestion or actually know where I may find this CSS?

Answer (score 0):

## Where to find `mat-select` classes?

To find them you can use the browser inspector or seeing the master css file:
https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/select/select.scss

## Globally

If you need to update it globally you can override one or more of those classes according to your need in your `style.css`.

## ::ng-deep

You can use [::ng-deep](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) (like `::ng-deep .mat-select-content`) to force the override the `mat-select` style in your component.

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-panel .mat-option {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

## ViewEncapsulation

You can the [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation) to `None` if you want to avoid to inherit the `mat-select` style imposed by Angular Material in your component.

#### Component Template

```
 import {ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
  ....
  @Component({
        ....
        encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
 })
```

#### Component Style

```
.mat-select-panel .mat-option {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Actually what I want is the opposite. I want to use the mat-select css in a simple select.